# Returning all values from SQLite using query()?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have a database with 3 columns (`Description`, `Priority` and `Date`) all of which are searchable by the user. I am trying to use the below code (which works with `null` in place of `selection` and `selcArgs`) to achieve this but it am not getting any results?

```
String selection = Table.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + "=? AND " + 
Table.COLUMN_PRIORITY + "=? AND " + Table.COLUMN_DATE + "=?";

// description, priority, date picked up from textboxes and DO pass values
String[] selcArgs = new String[] { description, priority, date };

ContentResolver().query(MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI,null, selection, selcArgs, sortBy)
```

If the user passes no values I would like to return all the the data in the DB. Similarly for if the user does not enter a value in one of the attributes, I would effectively like it to ignore that value.

I hope this is well enough explained!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: just found if I change the '=?' to 'LIKE ?' and pass '%' to the query all the values seem to be passed. Just doing some more tests but this may be my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `StringBuffer` for your selection and an `ArrayList` for the values then add conditions and values as needed:

```
final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
final ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

if (description != null) {
   sb.append(Table.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION).append("=?");
   values.add(description);
}

// ...
// check also if you have to add AND
// ...

ContentResolver().query(MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, sb.toString(), values.toArray(), sortBy);
```

Comment: as a value of "" cab be taken from the textEdits I am not sure if testing ' !=null ' would work? Apologies, but I think the ' LIKE ? ' may be the best solution.

Comment: But on the performance aspect of queries, less conditions implies a faster result